# Reverse sorting backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using the below function to sort a backbone collection. I am sorting the collection with reference to Date(creationdate). The output I am fetching has oldest item first, But I want the output to be as latest item first and the oldest item last.

```
var campaignsNewCampaigns = _.sortBy(campaigns, function(campaign) {
  if (campaign.creationdate) {
    var getDate = campaign.creationdate.replace("-", "").replace("-", "").replace(":", "").replace(":", "");

    return -Number(getDate);
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

```
if (campaign.creationdate) {
            var getDate = (new Date(campaign.creationdate)).getTime(); 
            return -Number(getDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In backbone.js, you have a comparator field and sort function.
To Set your collection sort, you should add this function on your collection :

```
//...
sortByDate : function(){
    this.comparator = function(campaign){
        // I consider creationDate is a Date Object
        return -campaign.get('creationdate').getTime();
    };
    this.sort();
},
//...
```

And now, to sort your collection, call this method like this :

```
var campaignsNewCampaigns = campaigns.sortByDate();
```

Comment: But i think your code doesnt seem to work on my page.  I will give you any other example                                             var campaignsTopPerformance = _.sortBy(campaigns, function(campaign) {
            if (campaign.max_ctr) {
                return -Number(campaign.max_ctr)
            }
            return 0;
        });                                                            in the above function i am sorting by max_ctr, and its working successfully.

Comment: i am already getting a sorted array but i want it in the reverse format.

Comment: You shouldn't set `this.comparator` just for the purpose of calling a one-off sort. Collection does implement `sortBy()` for that purpose.

Comment: you are right, if you should sort by default with this comparator, set this on collection.comparator field. @Rahul92 used you a backbone.js collection ?

Comment: @Azure can you give a specific coding structure, which will solve my need?

Comment: can you add your collection code in your post ? Normally, to access to module property, you should use the `get()` function and, in your examples, you can't use that. Your collection is attached to a backbone.js model ?

Comment: leave me your mail address i will send you the file.

Comment: in this example i am populating the backbone.view, I am defining all these functions inside the render function.